# How to pass tuple to function as separate variables

Tags: python

When returning multiple variables from a Python function, returning a tuple is the most convenient solution to me. However, it lacks convenience when chaining the return value with another function taking separate variables as input. For example, say we have

```
def foo():
    return (1,2)

def sum(a, b):
    return a+b
```

And in this case, the following chaining doesn't work

```
sum(foo())
```

I know one solution, namely to change the function `sum` to take a tuple as input rather than 2 vars, i.e.

```
def sum2((a, b)):
    return a+b
```

Now the chaining `sum2(foo())` works, but it's a bit awkward, isn't it? I wound rather change `foo()` because `sum()` might has been used by others. What is a nice solution to this?

Comment: @tom10 Oh, looks like I missed Python 101..What's the name for this? dereference?

Comment: @bl4cksun its called  argument unpacking

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for unpacking.  You should try -

```
sum(*foo())
```